# Entity Framework Core shows warning message

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

My entity classes:

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? UnitID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    // More fields

    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My query:

```
        return await DbContext.Unit.AsNoTracking().Include(r => r.Manufacturer)
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    UnitID = r.UnitID,
                    UnitName = r.Name,
                    ManufacturerName = r.Manufacturer.Name // Using Manufacturer
                }).ToListAsync();
```

The warning message:

> ...|WARN|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|The
>   Include operation for navigation '[r].Manufacturer' is unnecessary and
>   was ignored because the navigation is not reachable in the final query
>   results. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850303 for more
>   information...

I am using Manufacturer.name in new anonymous so It means navigation [r].Manufacturer must be used.

Why Entity Framework Core warns the message? Is am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: it works? I mean, it gives you the Manufacturer's name in the returning list?

Comment: _I am using Manufacturer.name in new anonymous so It means navigation [r].Manufacturer must be used._ Wrong. You only need the include when you want the property and it's **NOT** within the select lambda. Once you access any nav property int he select, the includes are **ignored**. You should just read the link in the exception, it explains it all

Comment: @Tseng: Does it means [r].Manufacturer will be loaded by default because I am using it in new anonymous? No need Include(r => r.Manufacturer)?

Comment: @Loc: Exactly, thats what the warning and the docs also tells you :)

Comment: @Tseng: Thanks!

Comment: When you do a projection (`.Select` statement which returns a non-entity type), the original entity won't be used and only the navigation properties used within it are really required. It would otherwise lead to bad performance to do additional joins (thats usually what happens on include) for non used nav properties

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually a common misconception about what Entity Framework’s [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include) actually does. It actually does not affect the filtering at all but is only relevant when the result is materialized.

When you do `something.Include(x => x.Prop)` then what you are actually telling Entity Framework is this: When there is an entity of the type of `something` in the result, then also include the entity that is reachable by the navigation property `Prop`.

For example, following the usual blogs & posts example that the EF Core documentation uses, `context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts)` will load the `Blog` entities and include the related `Posts` for each `Blog` entity. But this matters only if you actually select `Blog` entities in the result.

```
context.Blogs
    .Select(blog => new {
        Id = blog.BlogId,
        Url = blog.Url,
    });
```

This query for example does not produce any `Blog` entities, so includes on the `Blog` entity would be ignored. You could also expand this query to also include information about the posts, without actually having to include the `Posts` navigation property on the `Blog` entity. Since there’s no `Blog` entity in the result, that wouldn’t have any effect:

```
context.Blogs
    .Select(blog => new {
        Id = blog.BlogId,
        Url = blog.Url,
        PostCount = blog.Posts.Count(),
    });
```

Note that not including a navigational property does not prevent you from using it to filter something:

```
context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Posts.Any(post => title == "Foo"));
```

This would select all `Blog` entities that contained a post with a title “Foo”; but the `Posts` navigation property wouldn’t be loaded since it wasn’t included in the query. But you can still filter by it.

---

So `.Include()` will only affect the *result* of the query, and only if there is an actual entity of that type being produced. It is however not necessary to include something just to filter by it.

In your particular example, since there isn’t any `Unit` entity in the result, the inclusion of `Unit.Manufacturer` has no effect. And in order to add the `Unit.Manufacturer.Name` to the result, you do not need to include the navigation property.

Comment: Awesome, very well explained

Comment: how would I go about Including the PostCount in your example in the same query? currently your code produces n+1 sql queries?

Comment: @KristjanKica Which example are you referring to exactly? The second example, which has the `blog.Posts.Count()`, should give you all blogs and their post counts in a _single_ query.

Comment: Yes, I have a similar case, but I am passing an Expression<Func<Entity, DTO>> to the select statement insted of the lambda. The result is multiple queries for the navigation property. EF core 2.2.6

Comment: @poke looks like its a EF core 2 feature that related entities are retrieved in a separate query, however without materializing the query before Select(), every related entity is lazy loaded. So with `query.ToList().AsQuerable().Select(expression)`  there are 2 get statements, but with `query.Select(expression)` there are n+1 sql statements (n is number of parent records)